# Read JSON and plain text from stdout

Tags: fluentd

I have this `fluentd` filter:

```
<filter **>
  @type parser
  @log_level trace
  format json
  key_name log
  hash_value_field fields
</filter>
```

I'm writing some JSON to `stdout` and everything works as expected.

But when I'm also writing some plain non JSON text like `Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/459316ca-5ec5-43e4-ae5d-d4651eca2c9e` to `stdout` (or `stderr`), I get this error:

```
fluent/log.rb:342:warn: dump an error event: 
error_class=Fluent::Plugin::Parser::ParserError 
error="pattern not match with data 
'Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/459316ca-5ec5-43e4-ae5d-d4651eca2c9e'"
```

Is there a way to parse and forward both using `fluentd` without getting an error?

Would it even be possible to wrap the plain text in a `JSON` string like `{ message: "Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/459316ca-5ec5-43e4-ae5d-d4651eca2c9e" }`?

**Update** based on the answer from @Imran:

This is my `docker.compose.yml`:

```
version: "2"

services:

  fluentd:
     build: ../fluentd
     command: /bin/sh -c "/fluentd/config.sh && fluentd -c /fluentd/etc/fluent.conf -v"
     ports:
      - "24224:24224"
     environment: 
      - AWS_REGION
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  service:
    build:
      context: ../service
      args:
        - NPM_TOKEN
    command:  node --inspect=0.0.0.0 index.js
    ports:
       - "3000:80"
    volumes :
      - ../service/:/app
    logging:
      driver: fluentd
      options:
        fluentd-address: localhost:24224
        tag: 'docker.{{.ImageName}}.{{.Name}}.{{.ID}}'
```

This is my updated `fluent.conf`:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
</source>

# JSON-Parse
<filter docker.**>
  @type parser
  @log_level trace
  format json
  key_name log
  hash_value_field fields
</filter>

<label @ERROR>
  <match docker.**>
    @type stdout
  </match>
</label>

<match docker.**>
  @type stdout
  @include cw.conf
</match>
```

This is my `cw.conf`:

```
@type cloudwatch_logs
log_group_name dev-logs
log_stream_name dev
auto_create_stream true
```

The logs created from writing JSON to `stdout` are pushed correctly to CloudWatch but the `@ERROR` entries are not pushed to CloudWatch.

But they're logged correctly to `stdout` now:

```
2019-08-22 19:25:53.000000000 +0000 docker.integration_service.integration_service_1.2db3cc97a71a: {"container_name":"/integration_service_1","source":"stderr","log":"Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/94a655a4-1bbb-49
3e-abcc-f2637c39583d","container_id":"2db3cc97a71aa27c957fa13e29ac4c1c9f8a616c8c2989dcf72ea8f9b666d513"}
```

How can I push them to CloudWatch now as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's possible. By default, all the unmatched records are emitted to `@ERROR` label.

This is being done because `emit_invalid_record_to_error` flag is set to true.

Invalid cases are

1. key not exist
2. format is not matched
3. unexpected error

You can rescue unexpected format logs in @ERROR label.
If you want to ignore these errors, set `false`.

More documentation here.
https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser#emit_invalid_record_to_error

In your case, you want to capture **format is not matched** records. An example way is like below.

```
<filter myTag>
  @type parser
  @log_level trace
  key_name log
  hash_value_field fields
</filter>

<label @ERROR>
  <match myTag>
    @type stdout
  </match>
</label>
```

Above `match` within `label` emits the data in JSON to STDOUT with format you have desired.

> { message: "Debugger listening on
>   ws://0.0.0.0:9229/459316ca-5ec5-43e4-ae5d-d4651eca2c9e" }

Just try and let me know.

**Important Note** - `@ERROR` captures lot of internal fluentd errors and warnings so in-order to capture only the format not matched errors, I specifically provided `filter myTag`,`match myTag` which makes sure my filter & match process only my tag records and errors. I see that you are using `filter **` which performs filterging against all records so I would say best practice is to provide the correct `tag` for the `match`,`filter` etc.,

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it looks like I'm still missing something. I updated the question.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler I see there is difference in tag under filter(`<filter docker.**>`) vs match(`<match docker.** *>`) under label. is that just a typo?. Can you make them in sync and try again?.

Comment: Now I'm only getting the fluentd events into CloudWatch, no more output from within the service container.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler odd. when I tested above with just `@stdout`, it works fine for unmatched records. I am little bit confused on your use of both `@stdout` and `@include` in same match. Is it possible, can you just keep `@include` only?. Also, your final match is catching all events because of `match **`, maybe you want to modify to match only your tag events.

Comment: When replacing `@type stdout` by `@include cw.conf` in the `<label @ERROR>` section, it works. But now I have `fields.message` for JSON and `log` for plain text. Could I get `fields.message` for both?

Comment: Solved it using a transformer. Thanks for your help, I learned a lot from your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [multi-format parser plugin](https://github.com/repeatedly/fluent-plugin-multi-format-parser#for-v10) which can parse different formats. This way you can specify several pattern such as `format json` and `format none` and all logs are forwarded to the same destination, so you do not need to worry about handling some logs via `@ERROR`.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at it.